# Scoping out how to handle UGC dates/times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm scoping out how to handle user-generated dates with rails and was hoping to get some thoughts on the best way to handle them. Ultimately I want to display dates/times provided by the user in HTML, and I also want to sort by the dates (ascending and descending, depending). My initial thought was to create the db as time: string and date:string and then convert these strings to datetime values. Is there a better way to go about this? I'm using RoR 3.1.

Any thoughts and ideas would be greatly appreciated so I don't start down the wrong path only to realize at a later date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way to go about it. ActiveRecord supports the [following types for times](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types):

- datetime
- timestamp
- time
- date

So pick the type that matches your intent (`time` for time of day, `date` for a date, ...) and then let AR do its job and deal with the details. Then you'll get the right data in the database and the right objects in your Ruby; once you have the right objects in your Ruby everything will sort and compare and what not properly.

Comment: I had read that before and it had completely slipped my mind. Thanks again!